# customized form_for tag in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to make a table within a form by making a new form_tag. The following code in ApplicationHelper fails:

```
module ApplicationHelper

class TabularFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder 
   # ... code to insert <tr> tags </tr> 
end

def tabular_form_for(name, object = nil, options = nil, &proc) 
   concat("<table>", proc.binding) 
   form_for(name, 
   object, 
   (options||{}).merge(:builder => TabularFormBuilder), 
   &proc) 
   concat("</table>", proc.binding) 
  end
end
```

The view I use is:

```
<h1>New project</h1>
<% tabular_form_for :project, :builder => ApplicationHelper::TabularFormBuilder do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.text_area :description %>
  <%= f.text_field :location %>
  <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
<% end %>
```

The error I get is:

NoMethodError in Projects#new
   Showing app/views/projects/new.html.erb where line #5 raised:
   undefined method `errors' for {:builder=>ApplicationHelper::TabularFormBuilder}:Hash

Any ideas how to make this custom tag work?

Comment: hi poseid,

can u send some details on how you are calling this method and about parameters that you are passing

cheers,
sameera

Answer (score 0):

Is this posted verbatim? Because your second block needs to be within the closing `end` tag for it to access the FormBuilder class right?

I found the following tutorial which might help:
http://ramblingsonrails.com/how-to-make-a-custom-form-builder-in-rails